# Exposed on chain function for EdDSA/ed25519 signature verification

Tags: solana-program

I was wondering if on chain programs had a way to verify EdDSA signatures, besides importing (non std dependent) crypto libs, given that solana already does EdDSA checks for transaction/wallet signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there's a native program for that!

https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#ed25519-program